# HTML And Javascript Validation Check

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make it so that i can only insert 4 digits into the 'Exam ID Number' text box to perform a validation check, Also could anyone make it so that the box can only fit up to 4 digits in it so that it can only have 4 max, Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here is the code so far

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Exam Entry</title>

<script language="javascript"" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
            var result = true;
            var msg="";

if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your name \n";
            document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your Exam Number \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('Exam Number').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}


if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
            }


}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
  <table width="50%" border="0">
            <tr>
                            <td id="name">Name</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                            <td id="Exam Number">Exam Number</td>
                            <td><input type="Number" name="ID Number" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"     onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `maxlength="4"` to your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `maxlength` attribute

```
<input type="Number" name="ID Number" maxlength="4" />
```

Comment: Any idea how to make it validate that it is only 4 digits so that they cant enter any more or any less?

Comment: it will not allow user to enter more than 4 chars. it will stop at 4th char

Comment: Any suggestion where the code should go in the full code?

Comment: i really dont understand your question...."where the code should go in the full code?"

Comment: I meant where the code should be in the full script

Comment: it should be with in your body tag - where you have defined all of your HTML tags like input,form,p etc... (maxlength) is an attribute in input tag of type="text". You just need to add maxlength attribute in your input type="text" declarations.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is you have spaces in your ID's. Generally, that's not a good idea. Use camel case or underscores. `myID` or `my_id`  but not  `my id`

Use this for your html:

```
<input type="text" id="examNumber" name="examNumber" maxlength="4" />
```

By doing that, you really don't need javascript validation to check the length, the user will only be able to enter 4 digits.

You could check the user has entered *at least* 4 digits is like this (using jQuery):

```
if ( $('#examNumber').val().length !== 4 )
{
    alert('enter more digits, yo!');
}
```

Depending on if you are using the input type of "number" the element will only allow numbers to be entered. If you are using input type of "text", I would also recommend using the [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) method to make sure only numbers have been entered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Exam Entry</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="examForm" name="examForm" action="YOUR ACTION" method="post" />
        <fieldset>
              <legend for="examNumber">Exam Number</legend>
              <input type="text" id="examNumber" name="examNumber" maxlength="4" />
              <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
     $('#examForm').on('submit', funciton(event) {
         if (formIsValid) {
             $('#examForm').trigger('submit');
         }
          event.preventDefault();
      });
      function formIsValid() {
       if ( $('#examNumber').val().length !== 4 ) {
           return false;
       }
       else {
           if ( isNan($('#examNumber').val()) {
               return false;
           }
           else {
               return true;
           }
       }

       return false;
      }
})(jQuery);
</script>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I updated a sample code. I don't really want to do your work for you. However, this should get you going in the right direction. :)

Comment: Any idea on what the code will look like, could u put it where it should be? :)